# What does NS stand for in NSString or NSXMLParser in Cocoa objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the NS prefix mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473758/what-does-the-ns-prefix-mean)

Wondering the prefix of those classes within Cocoa objective-c on iphone.
What does NS stand for?