# Inherited properties and synthesizing in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, inheritance

I have the following class and subclass:

```
@interface NSHigh : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *array;
@end
@implementation NSHigh
-(NSArray*)array
{
    _array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    return _array;
}
@end

@interface NSLow : NSHigh
@end
@implementation NSLow
/* synthesizing makes the assertion FAIL. NO synthesizing makes the assertion PASS */
@synthesize array;
@end
```

Then I run this code somewhere:

```
NSLow *low = [[NSLow alloc] init];
assert(low.array);
```

So, apparently, if in the subclass `NSLow` I synthesize the array property, then the getter from the super class does not get called, and the assertion fails.

If I do not synthesize, then the superclass getter is called, and the assertion passes.

1. Why does this happen?
2. How would I access the array instance variable in the `NSLow` subclass without calling `self.array` every time?

Comment: Don't prefix your class names with `NS`. This is reserved by Apple.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan is this a precautionary measure, or will Apple reject the application as well?

Comment: Call it a language requirement.

Comment: For those who are interested, NS stands for NeXTSTEP where the Cocoa frameworks originally came from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/473866/159758

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@synthesize` in `NSLow` will create the following getter:

```
- (NSArray *)array {
    return _array;
}
```

So, your array is never initialized and `nil` is returned.

You generally shouldn't use `@synthesize` for `@properties` that are declared in a superclass.

Also, you shouldn't implement a getter like the one in `NSHigh`. If you want to init that array lazily you should do it like this:

```
- (NSArray *)array {
    if (!_array) {
        _array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _array;
}
```

Finally, you shouldn't use `NS` prefix.

**EDIT:**

If you want direct access to your ivar in the subclass, you can explicitly declare it in the header like this:

```
@interface NSHigh : NSObject {
    NSArray *_array;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *array;
@end
```

This will allow you to access the ivar in your subclasses too.

Comment: So I would have to explicitly call self.property from all subclasses? There's no other way around this? What's the reasoninng for this?

Comment: But if you really want direct access, you can explicitly declare your ivar in the superclasses interface.

Comment: @DrummerB Will a synthesized getter use the `_array` ivar? That is, with an underscore prefix?

Comment: Actually no, you're right. If you simply call `@synthesize array;` if will use an ivar called `array`. If you let it synthesize automatically it will use `_array`. Or you can also use `@synthesize array = _array;` to make it use `_array` when explicitly synthesizing.

Comment: Shouldn't that `if (_array) ...` be `if (!_array) ...`?