# UIWebView content blocked

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, xcode7

I'm working with a simple app just to load web pages using UIWebView, however when I tried to load some pages I got this message

"2016-06-21 14:45:13.568 Free Trials[34369:7398070] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file."

I went to the Info.plist file to remove this block, however I didn't know what to change, can anyone tell me what settings to change there so I can fix this block?
[image: that's my Info.plist]

Comment: Have you configure transport security dictionary in your info.plist?

Comment: @JigarTarsariya no I didn't, I don't know it even more

Comment: Srsly? A photo of your screen??? You should REALLY google how to take screenshots on a mac. It is 100 times faster than taking an image and syncing it around AND it is of far better quality

Comment: @luk2302 I had no internet connection on Mac while I was typing the question (I was on phone) and all what I had was my 4G on my iPhone. The only option was to take the photo with my phone. Of course I'm not waiting for you to tell me about that!

Comment: you can always share the internet connection of your phone with your mac, which would probably even make writing the question a lot easier for you.

Comment: @luk2302 I already did to test the app only as you should notice that it was an app to show internet pages, however I didn't use it to connect to Stackoverflow.com to save data plan and I already have an app for it on my iPhone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like below:

NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to YES under NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in your .plist file

[image]

Hope this help you.

Comment: I can't find it in my Info.plist

Comment: You will not find it but you have to specify it by clicking on + button besides the root key..

Comment: You need to specify it manually. If you still have issue then let me know

Comment: Sorry what's the root key?

Comment: See in your info.plist file, there is first row like - `Information property list`. Click there so there is one + button besides it. Click on it so it will add new row, then add this `NSAppTransportSecurity` key with type `Dictionary` and then click + button of this newly added row and add one more key `NSAllowsArbitaryLoads` type of Bool and set it `YES`.

Comment: I did it 1st but I thought I should find the NSAppTransportSecurity, however I didn't! I did it now

Comment: Away of the question, do u know what does NS that comes in the beginning of many codes stand for?

Comment: Yes, Cocoa classes begin with `NS` which stands for `NextStep`..please refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473758/what-does-the-ns-prefix-mean