# Building GIMP 2.10 from source on OSX fails on "gimp-debug-tool-2.0"

Tags: c++, git, build, open-source, gimp

I was trying to build GIMP 2.10 on OSX for a week now with no success. Most of the problems were all the different dependencies and such. While it took time all of it was solvable but now I think I came to an dead end. I have gone to the stage where I could finally run "make" and after some time of building different things it errors out on "gimp-debug-tool-2.0". Here is the output log:

```
Making all in app-tools
  CCLD     gimp-debug-tool-2.0
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSString", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libappwidgets.a(gimpcriticaldialog.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSWorkspace", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libappwidgets.a(gimpcriticaldialog.o)
  "_objc_autoreleasePoolPop", referenced from:
      _gimp_critical_dialog_response in libappwidgets.a(gimpcriticaldialog.o)
  "_objc_autoreleasePoolPush", referenced from:
      _gimp_critical_dialog_response in libappwidgets.a(gimpcriticaldialog.o)
  "_objc_msgSend", referenced from:
      _gimp_critical_dialog_response in libappwidgets.a(gimpcriticaldialog.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [gimp-debug-tool-2.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have got similar errors when I was building Qt, OpenCv applications. The problem there was that libraries were missing and I solved it by providing paths to those libraries. But what could possibly be missing when building "gimp-debug-tool-2.0" which seems to be internal tool.

If somebody had any similar experience or has any clue/hint on how I could solve this problem and could point me to the right direction it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Semi-educated guess: It looks like the build is trying to reference some Apple-specific items (objc ~= "Objective-C", NSString == "NeXTSTEP String", etc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473758/what-does-the-ns-prefix-mean) . You might need to provide some library paths to e.g., a copy of the OSX SDK in order to get the debug-tool to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is that gimp-debug-tool-2.0 is a new module that integrates with the OS X operating system to present a dialog in the event of an app failure.  It references NSString and NSWorkspace classes, which are part of OS X.  Therefore, you need to link against the appropriate OS X framework(s) to resolve the symbols.

Unfortunately, the automatic configure you run at the beginning of your build cycle references the `CoreFoundation` framework but this is not where NSString or NSWorkspace actually live.

The workaround for now is to include this as part of your LDFLAGS environment variable:

`-framework Foundation -framework AppKit`

This will allow the build to complete properly but is a bit of a hokey workaround.  The correct approach is to fix the auto-configure so that it references these frameworks properly in the first place but that's more complicated than I can manage

Comment: Brilliant! This definitely solved the problem with gimp debug tool and now it builds successfully. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that everything should have worked just fine despite for that debug tool. I do not actually need it so I was glad to skip building it. I ran make with -k flag which continues on error an luckily there were no other errors. After building and installing it runs just fine on my MacBook.

[GIMP 2.10.1 on OSX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DySdZ.png)