# Lightweight question : What do all these Apple acronyms actually stand for?

Tags: ios, apple-developer

What does.. 
NS stand for in `NSObject`,
SF stand for in `SFAuthenticationSession` and 
AS stand for in `ASWebAuthenticationSession`.

I assume there must be some logic behind these acronyms?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473758/what-does-the-ns-prefix-mean, `SF` is for Safari, and `AS` is for Authentication Services.

Comment: It works as a cheap form of name spacing when used in Objective-C. Prevents symbol collisions when you import multiple frameworks.

Comment: I found this https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/ that implies that for 'SF Symbols' the SF stands for San Francisco! Thanks for being so consistent, Apple :-)

Answer (score 2):

AS and SF are both acronyms made from its frameworks, AuthenticationService and SafariServices respectively. The NS acronym stands for [NeXTStep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeXTSTEP). Basically NeXTStep is the technology that early Cocoa was based on.

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful. And interesting that the acronym SF stands for Safari Services. So it's not an acronym at all. Apple huh!

Comment: Haha true. But it seems that inside Safari Services we have some [class/struct](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/#2191084) that starts with SS. Why? No idea.