# How to share/distribute compiled Objective-C code (like a JAR in Java)?

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, software-distribution

I would like to write some Objective-C code for distribution. What is the best way to package up the output. In Java you can package up your code in a JAR file and distribute that. What would be the equivalent in Objective-C?

The following link is close, but seems to address more of the namespace issues which I am not concerned about. I am mostly concerned about setting the code up for easy distribution.

[Objective-C equivalent of Java packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000707/objective-c-equivalent-of-java-packages)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A framework is almost certainly the way to go. One of the really nice things about Frameworks on OS X is that they can bundle the executable code, headers, metadata, images, icons, etc. in a single package. Further, frameworks can be included in `*/Library/Frameworks/` or even inside your app bundle to completely decouple from any other app's dependency on a given version of the framework.

**Apple's [Framework Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Frameworks.html)** is the best place to get started with frameworks.

Creating a framework is simple. Basically, in Xcode you choose *File > New Project...* and select Framework, then Cocoa Framework. This will set up a new project with framework target and automatically package everything up for you when you build.

Don't forget that documentation and unit tests are a Good Thing™, especially for frameworks, which are inherently more likely to be used by multiple clients than most end-user code. You can add more targets to your framework Xcode project to document and test it.

Since you're looking for examples, check out [CHDataStructures.framework](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/code/CHDataStructures) (a project which I develop) and [PSMTabBarControl.framework](http://www.positivespinmedia.com/dev/PSMTabBarControl) (which includes lots of extra resources in the framework). Both are open-source, and should provide adequate examples for rolling your own.

One word of advice to save you some head-scratching: your header files will not be copied to the built framework unless you click on the framework target and change the **Role** to "Public" (or "Private").

Comment: I down ticked this because the links provided are, more or less, broken. CHDataStructures.framework WebSVN contains nothing and PSMTabBarControl.framework result in 404.

Answer (score 5):

You want to create a Framework. There is a starting point in Xcode for a new project to create one of these. There are a few caveats and gotchas, but on the whole the process is straightforward.

Edit: For clarification: If you are planning to distribute it as FOSS; packing it up in a framework might be overkill; just distributing the source code might be a more sensible and simpler option. But if you would like to keep the source to yourself or distribute it with a collection of relevant resources, a framework might definitely be a good idea.

Reedit: For an introduction, see http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say if it was for iPhone or not.  On the iPhone, it needs to be a .sa (statically linked library) -- but I think the normal distribution would by a .dylib or .so

Comment: It would, quite actually, be a .framework; which is a .dylib packed in a folder hierarchy with relevant header files and resources.

Comment: Primarily iphone - but I may want to make it generic enough to work on the Mac too.

Answer (score 0):

You could compile it as a Framework or as a static library (.so I believe).

Answer (score -1):

Java programs run in the context of a virtual machine.  Jar contains abstract bytecodes which must be converted into native machine code by the VM.

Objective-C, like C, is compiled into native machine code, such as a Win .exe file, directly runnable by the operating system.

Most programs of any complexity consist of more than a single file and include DLLs, icon files, etc.  The configuration of your files for distribution would usually be handled by a setup utility.

Comment: The last part of this seems totally unrelated to Objective-C. There is no "setup utility", and thankfully, no DLL's in the same sense as Windows. Dynamic libraries on OS X can actually contain multiple versions, so clients can specifically link against a given version and not break if the library must violate backwards compatibility. Frameworks are the way to go.

Comment: Objective-C is not exclusive to OS X.