# Xcode xcconfig: Configuring a dependency based on the target

Tags: objective-c, xcode, project-settings, xcconfig

In the quest to resolve the Objective-C [namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474626/objective-c-function-dispatch-collisions-or-how-to-achieve-namespaces) [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178434/what-is-the-best-way-to-solve-an-objective-c-namespace-collision) I'd like to experiment with prefixing a dependency's Objective-C classes based on the target being built.

As an example, suppose I have in my shared library (`ObjCStaticLib`) a class (`CWindow`). I have two plugins (`A` and `B`) that will use this `CWindow`. To avoid `A`'s `CWindow` from colliding with `B`'s `CWindow`, I want to prefix the `CWindow` class name at compile time, so `A`'s `CWindow` becomes `ACWindow` and `B`'s becomes `BCWindow`.

I'm looking for a way to communicate to `ObjCStaticLib` at compile time what prefix it should use to compile itself with. I'm thinking about using [xcconfigs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/400-Build_Configurations/build_configs.html) to specify a preprocessor macro that the leaf target customizes and that `ObjCStaticLib` uses. However, I'm not aware of a way for a target to "communicate" with a dependency like that.

I can modify all the sources/projects/etc involved as necessary to implement per-client namespace customization in a dependency.

Does anyone have a good solution for this?

Comment: Can you describe your preprocessor idea a bit further?

Comment: That's why Apple's frameworks begin with AWindow and BWindow, not a generic CWindow. In short, if you have two static libs, you can't do this.

I'm not answering this as an answer since experience suggests it'll be voted down, not because it's inaccurate but because you won't like the fact that it's not possible. So I'm leaving it as a comment here for informational purposes only.