# How to have 2 objective C class with same name in a same project?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to solve an Objective-C namespace collision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178434/what-is-the-best-way-to-solve-an-objective-c-namespace-collision)

I was using 2 open source projects in an application with different use --- the issue was that both project had same class name with different implementations.

As per my understanding objective C don't have namespace option to handle scope --- as of now I am renaming the one of the class and its usage to make it work in my project.

Is there any alternative solution then renaming? I feel like objective C is missing namespace.

Comment: They do use it, eg. <uikit/uikit.h> etc.. Not sure how to implement it though :S.

Comment: @Sailesh This has nothing to do with namespaces. It's just organization of files.

Comment: it might be instructive to share the class name that caused the collision, as well as the names of the two frameworks.

Answer (score 6):

Renaming is the correct way. There is a reason why [Apple recommends to prefix your classes with some uppercase letters](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-1002226). This should prevent exactly this situation. Same for method names in class extension, or "private" methods.

Comment: Fortunately if you add one library and use Xcode's refactoring to rename the offending classes you're unlikely to make a mistake. Then, obviously, add the other library.

Comment: rename is the way that is what I am using now --- hard path for rename in my case is - if I have to use latest version of open source in some other day I have to rename it again ... this is why I am looking for a better solution then rename.

Comment: Convince the open source project to prefix their classes, you are likely not the only one who runs into this problem - now or later. You might get away with #define magic to rename the files in a small framework with minimal changes.

Comment: Since any decent Objective-C framework already uses a reasonably well thought-out prefix, name collisions are rare. Not impossible, though, unfortunately, as you've already discovered.

Comment: @jlehr: Did I miss the names of the frameworks here?

Comment: @Eiko: Sorry, I wasn't responding to your comment, just making a general observation (should have made that clear though). I don't believe the OP shared the name of the class or of the frameworks for that matter.