# Problem with duplicate classes in JSON frameworks ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, duplicates, sbjson

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to solve an Objective-C namespace collision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178434/what-is-the-best-way-to-solve-an-objective-c-namespace-collision)

In my app I used the SBJSON framework (Stig Brautaset's) to interact with my json api and everything worked very well.

But now I am in a situation to  use the Facebook SSO using facebook SDK. So I included the facebook sdk into my project as instructed in [Facebook developer site.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/)

**But the problem is, the facebook sdk too used some SBJSON classes like SBJsonParser, SBJsonWriter, etc that are already present in SBJSON framework that I used. These classes are similar in name but different in  methods and properties. So neither I can delete , nor edit any of them.  (I am a beginner and i don't know how to edit them without losing anything).**

So it shows many errors because of duplicate classes.

**What I can do here? Please help me :)**

header files (.h) of both JSonParser classes are given below. (.m files cannot be given here because they are too lengthy.)

**JSonParser.h that is used in Facebook SDK given below**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SBJsonBase.h"

@protocol SBJsonParser
- (id)objectWithString:(NSString *)repr;

@end

@interface SBJsonParser : SBJsonBase <SBJsonParser> {

@private
const char *c;

}   
@end


@interface SBJsonParser (Private)

- (id)fragmentWithString:(id)repr;

@end
```

**JSonParser.h that is used in SBJson Framework given below**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SBJsonParser : NSObject {


NSString *error;
NSUInteger depth, maxDepth;

}

@property NSUInteger maxDepth;

@property(copy) NSString *error;

- (id)objectWithData:(NSData*)data;

- (id)objectWithData:(NSData*)data;

- (id)objectWithString:(NSString*)jsonText error:(NSError**)error;


@end
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Have you ever fixed this? Im having the same probkem right now..

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide which SBJson implementation to keep, and then manually deleting the other one from your project setup.

The main problem is that there is allot of good iOS open source available. But the methods for distribution of this open source is arcane at best. No more advanced or fool proof than copying code on USB-sticks.

I have written a longer blog post on the topic titled *The state of iOD Open Source: and what to do about it*: http://blog.jayway.com/2011/05/16/the-state-of-ios-open-source-and-what-to-do-about-it/

My suggestion is to use the ability to have Xcode projects as dependencies for other Xcode projects. It works well, and I have used this method for over 5 years with good results.

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) but I cannot delete any of the framework because both are necessary for my project. I am searching for some other solution around.

Comment: @S.Philip -  Not delete the frameworks. You have to go into one of the framworks and delete the duplicate files from it. This is the major flaw of most iOS frameworks; very few of them works as is if you combine them, and re-use between them is pretty much non-existing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Remove one of the frameworks by deleting the reference to the files.
- Choose each of the duplicate classes, and select the word representing the name (like `JSonParser.h`).
- In Xcode, use the "Refactor..." menu item to rename it.
- Reimport the removed framework.

Make sure you make a snapshot before so you can revert if something goes wrong.