# Can I get clang to use custom classes for Objective-C literal objects?

Tags: objective-c, clang

The gcc documentation makes reference to an [`-fconstant-string-class`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constant-string-objects.html) argument, that lets you change the class used for `@"Objective-C string literal"` instances. I find that this doesn't appear to work with clang, using this source:

```
#import <stdio.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface ConstantString
{
    Class isa;
    char *c_string;
    unsigned int len;
}
@end
@implementation ConstantString

- (Class)class {return isa;}

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", class_getName([@"foo" class]));
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with this compiler in this way:

> $ clang -v
>
> Apple clang version 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-421.10.60) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
>
> Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0
>
> Thread model: posix
>
> $ clang -fconstant-string-class=ConstantString -lobjc constantstring.m
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
>
> ```
>   CFString in constantstring-C7icsk.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> ```
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

If I link against Foundation, then I find it's still using the default constant string class:

> $ clang -fconstant-string-class=ConstantString -lobjc constantstring.m
> -framework Foundation
>
> $ ./a.out
>
> __NSCFConstantString

So can you actually define a custom class for string literals using clang? And can the class of array, dictionary and number literals be changed?

Comment: There's a similar [SO question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252392/can-the-new-llvm-objective-c-literals-be-redirected-to-custom-classes)

Comment: I've definitely seen references to -fconstant-string-class in llvm code, so I believe it's supposed to work.  [This](http://www.mentby.com/Group/objc-language/new-literals-hardcoded-to-foundation.html) leads me to believe it's a known bug.

Comment: of course it works, its just not going to link to your code.  Its not supposed to.

Comment: A code generation option that is "not going to link to your code" does not sound plausible, @stackmonster. Can you explain more what you mean? What does the option do that means that "it works"?

Comment: You have no reason to replace that class and the difficulty you are experiencing is by design.

Comment: @stackmonster the design is supposed to enable swapping the class used for literal constant strings. Evidently the inability to do so is not by design.