# Objective-C class as C pointer type

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, automatic-ref-counting

`clang builtin function "__builtin_NSStringMakeConstantString"` returns const `NSConstantString*`,

that is not an Objective-C retainable object.

I want to replace this function with my own, but there seems to be no way to declare `NSConstantString* as non-Objective-C pointer in Objective-C++` (you can do it in Objective-C by using `struct NSConstnatString*`). I am sure, that this function returns `NSConstantString`, because the following two lines output `PK16NSConstantString`:

```
printf("%s\n", typeid(__builtin___NSStringMakeConstantString("foo")).name());
printf("%s\n", typeid(const NSConstantString*).name());
```

Whenever I try to execute the following code I get error "Cannot initialize a variable of type 'const NSConstantString *' with an rvalue of type 'const NSConstantString *'":

```
const NSConstantString* a = __builtin___NSStringMakeConstantString("foo");
```

Everything works OK if I add **bridge cast, so this means that NSConstantString* is returned as "raw" Objective-C pointer, but I have to create a function that returns exactly the same result as "__builtin**_NSStringMakeConstantString", so I have no option to use __bridge.

Whenever I try to return const NSConstantString* from a function, it is always returned as an Objective-C retainable pointer and there seems to be no way to declare it as C pointer except this:

```
typedef typeof __builtin___NSStringMakeConstantString("") rawNSConstnatStringPtr;
```

So the question is: Is there a way to declare a nonretainable pointer to NSConstantString* (without using typeof)?

Comment: did you try __bridge ?

Comment: I have no option to use __bridge, I need to create an exact copy of "__builtin___NSStringMakeConstantString" function, but I can't find a way to return "raw" C pointer to NSConstantString.

Comment: `NSString *str = (__bridge NSString*)a;`

Comment: bridge would not modify the pointer...

Comment: or dont use arc and forget the bridged cast

Comment: I must use ARC, and have no option to use __bridge so I need to find some clang flag or something that disables the ARC for given pointer. You can see that I can do this with "typedef typeof __builtin___NSStringMakeConstantString("")", but I am searching for cleaner solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You think `_builtin__NSStringMakeConstant` returns `NSConstantString`, because the compiler is tricking you.

I suggest you check out the clang source code: http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#git-mirror

Then search the source code: `git grep __builtin___NSStringMakeConstantString`.  You find that it's defined in `include/clang/Basic/Builtins.def` like this:

```
BUILTIN(__builtin___NSStringMakeConstantString, "FC*cC*", "nc")
```

The second argument is the function signature, and the comment at the top of the file explains what it means.  The `FC*` part is the return type, and means “constant CFString const pointer”. That makes sense since `CFString` and `NSString` are toll-free bridged.

But it doesn't make sense because the error message specifically mentions `NSConstantString`.  So `git grep -w NSConstantString` to see where that's coming from.  You eventually find method `ASTContext::getCFConstantStringType` in `lib/ast/ASTContext.cpp`.  This method creates a struct type declaration with the identifier `NSConstantString`, but it never adds the declaration to any scope (it doesn't call `PushOnScopeChains` or `AddDecl`).  So the `NSConstantString` identifier can appear in diagnostics, but you cannot access the type by name in your source code.  The `NSConstantString` type declared in `NSString.h` is, as far as the compiler is concerned, unrelated to this synthesized type.

Anyway, the important question is **why** you want to override `__builtin___NSStringMakeConstantString`, which you did not say.  If it's because you want to use your own constant string class, you're going about it the wrong way.

I don't think you **can** override that function, because it is built in to the compiler.  You would need to modify the compiler source code if you want to change its meaning.

Also, I don't think the compiler actually uses that function to create Objective-C string literals.  Running `git grep __builtin___NSStringMakeConstantString` doesn't turn up any places where the compiler generates a call to it.  The compiler handles `@"string"` syntax in `lib/Parse/ParseObjc.cpp` and `lib/Sema/SemaExprObjC.cpp` (look for methods named `ParseObjCStringLiteral` in both files).  The compiler looks up the `NSConstantString` type by name (which means it should get the one from the `NSString.h` header file) and creates an instance of `ObjCStringLiteral` with that type.

You should be able to make it look up a different class for the constant string type (instead of `NSConstantString`) using the `-fconstant-string-class` command-line flag, but I don't know how well that works.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11916753/77567) implies that it might not work.  Even if it does work, I think you're constrained to using the same memory layout as `NSConstantString`, in which case, why bother using a different class?

Comment: Thank you! I must use NSConstantString because I am transforming client's code (replacing "__builtin___NSStringMakeConstantString" with a function that deobfuscates an obfuscated string in memory) and it must remain the same after my transformations. If he uses it in templates or as a parameter to function, the result type must remain the same. I guess I have to stick with the "typeof __builtin___NSStringMakeConstantString("")" if there are no other options.