# Box Custom Struct in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, struct, objective-c-literals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to wrap a Struct into NSObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691881/how-to-wrap-a-struct-into-nsobject)
>   [Can the new Clang Objective-C literals be redirected to custom classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252392/can-the-new-clang-objective-c-literals-be-redirected-to-custom-classes)

I have a custom struct:

```
typedef struct {
    float f1;
    float f2;
} MYCustomStruct;
```

that I need to add to an `NSArray`. I've already written a category to create `NSValues` of these structs, which I then add to the `NSArray`, however I'd like to simplify that even further using boxed expressions, if possible. I'd love to be able to do this:

```
@[@(instanceOfMYCustomStruct)];
```

however, I'm confronted with the following error:

> Illegal type 'MYCustomStruct' used in a boxed expression

Is there a way to use boxed expressions with custom structs?

Comment: This question might answer your problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252392/can-the-new-clang-objective-c-literals-be-redirected-to-custom-classes

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691881/how-to-wrap-a-struct-into-nsobject

Comment: Even if you could box it - how would you get it out? A simple cast wouldn't work, and you can't return an unknown type (unless it's a pointer) from a function in objc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a [`NSValue`](https://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to box a struct, as it has built-in support for it. Unfortunately, you cannot use objective-c's cool literals for it, though:

```
struct foo myStruct;
NSValue *val = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&myStruct objCType:@encode(typeof(myStruct))];

// to pull it out...
struct foo myStruct;
[val getValue:&myStruct];
```

While this may be unwieldy & ugly amidst other objc code, you have to ask yourself - why are you using a `struct` in the first place in Objective-C? There are few speed performances gained over using an object with a few `@property`(s), the only real reason I could see is if you are integrating with a C library for compatibility with memory layouts, and even then, the structure of an objective-c object's memory layout is well-defined, so long as the superclass doesn't change.

So *what is your real purpose in boxing a struct*? If we have that, we can help you further.

Comment: If you use Objective-C++ you could define an overloaded Box() function that takes in your struct and returns an NSValue. Or just name the function B() for brevity and doesn't need more characters than Objective-C's boxing syntactic sugar.

Comment: With Objective-C++ you could also define an `operator NSValue*(const struct myStruct*)` that converts it seamlessly.

Comment: @adib true, and in some situations that may be acceptable, but that does mean that the struct is no longer a POD.

Comment: The `struct` can still be a plain sequence of bytes -- just define the `operator` as a freestanding function (instead of a member function).

Comment: There totally should be a NSValue boxing literal syntax on Clang. Maybe I'll write a patch...

Comment: typedef struct __attribute__((objc_boxable)) {
  float f1;
} myType;
myType a;    NSValue *val = @(a);

Comment: @paulotorrens  use __attribute__((objc_boxable))