# Adding AFNetworking to project with static lib what us AFNetworking

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to add AFNetworking to my project but i think one of my Static lib is using this framework. my question is how i can do it (add the AFNetworking into my project,the best will be without using pods ) and how i can be sure that this Static lib is really using AFNetworking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the symbols of a static library using the command line:

```
nm yourlibrary.a
```

This will print all the symbols and then you can check if `AFNetworking` is there.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nm.1.html

Comment: i can see that the static lib is using AFNetworking, now how i can add AFNetworking to my project and use it? i am getting duplicate symbols for architecture i386

Comment: Try this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178434/what-is-the-best-way-to-solve-an-objective-c-namespace-collision